# Problemas con Many2many odoo

Tags: python, odoo

Tengo una gran duda:

He creado 2 modelos :

```
status = [(1,'Vigente'),(2,'Caducado')]

class DateOfert(models.Model):
    _name = 'date.ofert'
    ofert_status = fields.Selection(status , string='Estatus Comercial')
    date_i = fields.Date(string='Fecha Inicial ')
    date_f = fields.Date(string='Fecha Final')
    ofert_c = fields.Many2many('comercial.ofert',string='Oferta Comercial')

class ComercialOfert(models.Model):
    _name = "comercial.ofert"
    n_dues = fields.Integer('N° de cuotas', size=2, required=True, help="Ingrese la cantidad de cuotas")
    money_i = fields.Float('Monto Inicial', required=True, help="Ingrese el precio inicial de la oferta")
    money_f = fields.Float('Monto Final', required=True, help="Ingrese hasta el precion final de la oferta comercial")
    t_pay = fields.Many2one('account.payment.term', 'N° de Dias de creditos', select=True)
    discount = fields.Integer('% Descuento', size=2, required=True)
```

Abajo he creado en un decorador en el metodo tengo el siguiente segmento del cotigo que quiero trata de obtener money_i del modelo date.ofert que el atributo es ofert_c es tipo Many2many.

```
context = self.env['date.ofert'].search([])
        for element in context:
            if element.ofert_status == 1:
                print(element.ofert_c.money_i)
```

y me muestra este error :

```
File "C:\proy\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 904, in __get__
  File "C:\proy\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 4823, in ensure_one
ValueError: Expected singleton: comercial.ofert(1, 2)
```

Ayudaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionado de esta manera :
if element.ofert_c:
                    for data in element.ofert_c:
                            cuota = data.n_dues
                            self.n_cuotas = int(cuota)